# Installing compiler packages

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, compiling

I am totally new to Linux. All my studies are now dependent on it. So I've installed Ubuntu in my laptop. I need to install few software packages for my compiler course to run llvm (I am following the instructions from http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html). Following are the packages I need to install:

Package     Version
GNU Make    3.79, 3.79.1;
GCC     >=4.7.0;
python  >=2.7;
GNU M4  1.4;
GNU Autoconf    2.60;
GNU Automake    1.9.6;
libtool     1.5.22;
zlib    >=1.2.3.4;

I will be using sudo apt-get install...............build-essential. Can anyone tell me what should I insert in the dot dot area to install all of the above? Also, do need to install Z and Zlibc? if yes, then what are their purposes?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using and what version of llvm do you need? Do you *really* need to do anything more than install the standard binary package of llvm from the repository (`sudo apt-get install llvm` - or use the Software Center)?

Comment: Hi. my Ubuntu version is 14.04. I am not sure about the llvm version. I'm just following the instructions from their site and that does not use the sudo apt-get command to install llvm. I already configured it but I need to install the other packages to compile llvm.

Answer (score 1):

**I have tried to answer your question as it stands: however please read this first**

**[How to install Ubuntu software when you're an ex-Windows user!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu/575161#575161)**

**and seriously consider whether the instructions you are following are appropriate and necessary.**

---

In general, you will need to use `apt-cache` (or browse the Software Center) - along with a little common sense. For example:

```
$ apt-cache policy m4
m4:
  Installed: 1.4.17-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.4.17-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.17-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

tells me that my system (Ubuntu 14.04) already has `m4 version 4.17` (specifically, the Ubuntu build `1.4.17-2ubuntu1`) and that it's already installed. If it wasn't already installed, then the package I would need to add to the `apt-get` command would simply be `m4`.

Sometimes, things are a little trickier. For example

```
$ apt-cache policy zlib
N: Unable to locate package zlib
```

in which case we need to do a bit of guesswork - let's try

```
$ apt-cache search devel | grep zlib
zlib1g-dbg - compression library - development
zlib1g-dev - compression library - development
libkaz-dev - Kazlib's reusable data structure development tools
gambas3-gb-compress-bzlib2 - Gambas bzlib2 component
gambas3-gb-compress-zlib - Gambas zlib compression component
gauche-zlib - zlib binding for Gauche
lua-zlib-dev - zlib development files for the Lua language
```

from which we might deduce that the actual primary zlib development package is probably `zlib1g-dev`; let's dig a little deeper

```
$ apt-cache show zlib1g-dev
Package: zlib1g-dev
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 443
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Mark Brown <broonie@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: zlib
Version: 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
Provides: libz-dev
Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1), libc6-dev | libc-dev
Conflicts: zlib1-dev
Filename: pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g-dev_1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size: 183378
MD5sum: baf554d3c4a2cc8b2d9a190c04e9e3d7
SHA1: b5c073d1a419915ed9c3047d2f04aaed24268c47
SHA256: d44332327123a4fef16ededcffac98ac0425402f9c2ccc8e42193b122f8a54b8
Description-en: compression library - development
 zlib is a library implementing the deflate compression method found
 in gzip and PKZIP.  This package includes the development support
 files.
Description-md5: d7f4e8a626131fc83c643c5d59096290
Multi-Arch: same
Homepage: http://zlib.net/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
```

OK - that indeed sounds like the thing we need - so what is its version in the repository?

```
$ apt-cache policy zlib1g-dev 
zlib1g-dev:
  Installed: 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

i.e. version `1.2.8`, again exceeding the minimum requirement (1.2.3.4) of the software you are trying to build.